# How to limit the search scope without regex lookbehinds?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Given a regular expression, I can easily decide where to start looking for a match from in a string using `lastIndex`.
Now, I want to make sure that the match I get doesn't go past a certain point in the string.

I would happily enclose the regular expression in a non-capturing group and append, for instance, `(?<=^.{0,8})`.

But how can I achieve the same goal without lookbehinds, that still aren't globally supported?

Note:

- While it might be the only reasonable fallback, slicing the string is not a good option as it results in a loss of context for the search.

### Example

https://regex101.com/r/7bWtSW/1

with the base regular expression that:

- matches the letter 'a', at least once and as many times as possible
- as long as an 'X' comes later

We can see that we can achieve our goal with a lookbehind: we still get a match, shorter.
However, if we sliced the string, we would lose the match (because the lookahead in the base regular expression would fail).

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern in the regex demo `(?:a+(?=.*X))(?<=^.{0,4})` uses a lookbehind assertion with that can yield multiple separate matches.

See a regex demo for the same pattern with [multiple matches](https://regex101.com/r/zqVAqH/1) in the same string

Without using a lookbehind, you can not get those separate matches.

What you might do is use an extra step to get all the matches for consecutive `a` char over matched part that fulfills the length restriction (In this case the group 1 value)

```
^([^\nX]{0,3}a)[^\nX]*X
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\nX]{0,3}a` Match 0-3 times a char other than a newline or X and then match `a`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\nX]*X` Match optional chars other than a newline or `X` and then match `X`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EHUkVX/1)

```js
const regex = /^([^\nX]{0,3}a)[^\nX]*X/;
[
  "aaaaaaaaX",
  "baaaaaaaaX",
  "bbaaaaaaaaX",
  "bbbaaaaaaaaX",
  "bbbbaaaaaaaaX",
  "babaaaaaaaaX",
  "aX",
  "abaaX"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1].match(/a+/g))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!
A hacky rewrite of the pattern itself, which could be anything, wouldn't probably be a solution in practice, though.

Answer (score 0):

Slice the match instead of slicing the string.

In your example, you want the match to account for the positive lookahead for `X`. But `X` is outside the limited scope, so we don't want to limit the *search scope*, essentially slicing the string, instead we want to **limit match length relative to its position in the string**.

To do that we'll use the `index` property of the returned match array.

```js
const string = 'aaaaaaaX'
const regex = /a+(?=X)/

function limitedMatch(string, regex, lastIndex) {
  const match = string.match(regex)
  const {index} = match;
  const matchLength = Math.max(lastIndex - index,0)
  return match[0].slice(0, matchLength)
}

console.log(limitedMatch(string, regex, 4))
console.log(limitedMatch(string, regex, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately, trimming the match is not adequate. It could yield a result that isn't a match itself while also even skipping an actual match that is contained in that portion of match.
Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/ZLSA4K/1

Comment: Essentially you have 3 scenarios. 1. When your regex has a positive lookahead that you want to include. In that case I would suggest match slicing. 2. When you have a quantifier, which will produce multiple matches (disregarding the non capturing group), in that case, JS includes all the sub matches i.e. ['abc','abcabc'] in the array, and you can compare their lengths to maximum match length, and use the applicable ones. 3. If you have a regex without lookaheads or quantifiers. If it extends beyond the limit,  the lookbehind won't match it, so if a regex fits that criteria, slice the input.

Comment: There might be a way at some point if we’re diving into some regex meta-analysis or rewriting an entire regex engine, but that wasn’t really my intent. A few considerations on this suggestion, however:
1. If your match is going past the limit, slicing it will still likely result in a string that isn’t match.

Comment: 2. When you have a quantifier, whether greedy or non-greedy, the engine matches it and moves forward. You don’t get “submatches” neither with match(), matchAll() nor exec(). If you’re to iterate yourself with exec() and play around way too much with lastIndex (disregarding performance issues), you’re still going to miss out on smaller matches starting at the same positions of longer ones (think of 0-length matches that force you to increment lastIndex not to get stuck) that you will come not to be interested in because they’re too long.

Comment: You're right about the multiple matching only returning one match. Overall these interactions with postiive lookbehidn and definitely very interesting, and replicating them does sound like a deeper problem than it may seem at first. Maybe comparing matches of sliced input vs full input can be a step in some helpful direciton.